# How to use NFS mount for Docker on MacBook

Tags: docker

Currently Docker is too slow on Mac. As a solution I was trying to implement the process as mentioned in https://vivait.co.uk/labs/docker-for-mac-performance-using-nfs

I've docker-compose.yml that's working fine on Linux

```
version: '3.6'

services:
    traefik:
      image: traefik:1.7.12
      ports:
        - ${COMPOSE_PORT_HTTP}:80
        - ${COMPOSE_PORT_HTTPS}:443
      volumes:
        - "docker_mount:/var/run/docker.sock"
        - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
        - ./traefik/ssl/:/ssl/
        - ./logs:/logs
      container_name: traefik
      labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}"
          - "traefik.backend=traefik"
          - "traefik.port=8080"    

    nginx:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: nginx
      hostname: nginx
      volumes:
          - ../code_app/:/code_app/:rw
          - ../code_email/:/code_email/:rw
          - ../code_emailvalidation/:/code_emailvalidation/:rw
          - ../code_msas/:/code_msas/:rw
          - ../code_msms/:/code_msms/:rw
          - ../code_mockserver/:/code_mockserver/:rw
          - ./include/nginx_local/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro
      depends_on:
          - php-fpm
      networks:
        default:
          aliases:
            - nginx-app-api
            - nginx-msms            
            - nginx-msas
            - nginx-mockserver
      labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=HostRegexp:{catchall:.*}"
          - "traefik.frontend.priority=1"
          - "traefik.backend=nginx"
          - "traefik.port=80"    

    app-redis:
      image: redis:alpine
      container_name: app-redis
      hostname: app-redis

    msms-redis:
      image: redis:alpine
      container_name: msms-redis
      hostname: msms-redis

    mockserver-redis:
      image: redis:alpine
      container_name: mockserver-redis
      hostname: mockserver-redis

    msas-redis:
      image: redis:alpine
      container_name: msas-redis
      hostname: msas-redis

    email-redis:
      image: redis:alpine
      container_name: email-redis
      hostname: email-redis

    phpredisadmin:
      container_name: phpredisadmin
      hostname: phpredisadmin
      image: erikdubbelboer/phpredisadmin
      environment:
          - REDIS_1_HOST=app-redis
          - REDIS_1_NAME=app-redis
          - REDIS_2_HOST=msms-redis
          - REDIS_2_NAME=msms-redis
          - REDIS_3_HOST=msas-redis
          - REDIS_3_NAME=msas-redis
          - REDIS_4_HOST=email-redis
          - REDIS_4_NAME=email-redis
          - REDIS_5_HOST=mockserver-redis
          - REDIS_5_NAME=mockserver-redis
      labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:redis-web.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}"
          - "traefik.backend=redis-web"
          - "traefik.port=80"

    mariadb:
      image: mariadb:10.2
      container_name: mariadb
      hostname: mariadb
      volumes:
        - ./backup:/backup
      ports:
        - ${COMPOSE_PORT_MYSQL}:3306
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

    mongo:
      image: mongo:3.6
      command: --smallfiles
      container_name: mongo
      hostname: mongo
      ports:
        - ${COMPOSE_PORT_MONGO}:27017
      #environment:
      #  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      #  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

    mongo-express:
      image: mongo-express
      container_name: mongo-express
      hostname: mongo-express
      depends_on:
          - mongo
      labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mongo-express.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}"
          - "traefik.backend=mongo-express"
          - "traefik.port=8081"

    rabbitmq:
      image: rabbitmq:3-management
      hostname: rabbitmq
      container_name: rabbitmq
      #ports:
      #  # Management port
      #  - "15672:15672"
      #  # Service port
      #  - "5672:5672"
      labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:rabbitmq.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}"
          - "traefik.backend=rabbitmq"
          - "traefik.port=15672"
      #volumes:
      #  # Database mount
      #  - ./db_rabbitmq/:/var/lib/rabbitmq

    php-fpm:
      build:
        context: ./include/php-fpm
      container_name: php-fpm
      hostname: php-fpm
      # xdebug idekey "PHPSTORM"
      # xdebug port 9001
      volumes:
        # TimeFix
        #- /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        # GeoIP
        #- ./docker_files/db_geoip/:/application/storage/app/geoip2/
        # CRON
        #- ./docker_files/cron/php-fpm_laravel_schedule:/etc/cron.d/cron
        - ../code_app/:/code_app/:rw
        - ../code_email/:/code_email/:rw
        - ../code_emailvalidation/:/code_emailvalidation/:rw
        - ../code_msas/:/code_msas/:rw
        - ../code_msms/:/code_msms/:rw
        - ../code_mockserver/:/code_mockserver/:rw

    php-fpm-horizon:
      build:
        context: ./include/php-fpm-horizon
      container_name: php-fpm-horizon
      hostname: php-fpm-horizon
      depends_on:
          - rabbitmq
      volumes:
        - ../code_app/:/code_app/:rw
        - ../code_msms/:/code_msms/:rw        
        - ../code_email/:/code_email/:rw
        - ../code_emailvalidation/:/code_emailvalidation/:rw
        - ../code_mockserver/:/code_mockserver/:rw
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:supervisor.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}"
        - "traefik.backend=horizon-supervisor"
        - "traefik.port=8001"

    phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      container_name: phpmyadmin
      hostname: phpmyadmin
      environment:
        #- PMA_ARBITRARY=1
        - PMA_USER=root
        - PMA_PASSWORD=root
        - PMA_HOST=mariadb
      depends_on:
        - mariadb
#      ports:
#        - 8080:80
      volumes:
        - /sessions
      labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:phpmyadmin.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}"
          - "traefik.backend=phpmyadmin"
          - "traefik.port=80"

    mailhog:
      image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
      container_name: mailhog
      labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mailhog.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}"
          - "traefik.backend=mailhog"
          - "traefik.port=8025"

    nodejs:
      image: node:9-alpine
      #build:
      #  context: ./include/vuejs-watch
      container_name: nodejs
      hostname: nodejs
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - ../code_app/:/code_app/:rw
          - ../code_email/:/code_email/:rw
          - ../code_msas/:/code_msas/:rw
          - ../code_msms/:/code_msms/:rw
      command: echo "Container ready."

    elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.8.2
        container_name: elasticsearch
        environment:
          - http.host=0.0.0.0
          - transport.host=localhost
          - network.host=0.0.0.0
          - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
        labels:
          - "traefik.enable=false"
        ulimits:
          memlock:
            soft: -1
            hard: -1
        networks:
          - default

    graylog:
        image: graylog/graylog:3.2
        container_name: graylog
        labels:
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.web.port=9000"
            - "traefik.web.frontend.rule=Host:graylog.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}"
            - "traefik.web.backend.healthcheck.path=/"
            - "traefik.web.backend.healthcheck.interval=10s"
        environment:
          # CHANGE ME (must be at least 16 characters)!
          - GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=somepasswordpepper
          # Password: admin
          - GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2=8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
          - GRAYLOG_HTTP_BIND_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9000
          # - GRAYLOG_HTTP_PUBLISH_URI=http://0.0.0.0:9000
          - GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI=https://graylog.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}/
          - GRAYLOG_ROOT_TIMEZONE=Asia/Nicosia
        networks:
          - default
        depends_on:
          - mongo
          - elasticsearch
        ports:
          # Graylog web interface and REST API
          - 9000:9000
          # Syslog TCP
          - 1514:1514
          # Syslog UDP
          - 1514:1514/udp
          # GELF TCP
          - 12201:12201
          # GELF UDP
          - 12201:12201/udp

networks:
  default:
    name: intergo-local-net
    driver: bridge
```

How would I use the NFS Mount to be integrated on the docker-compose.yml attached?

Answer (score 0):

Following your example page, you need to declare your version of the NFS at the root level (same level as 'services') and then add the name you chose to any volumes you want on the NFS as shown.

I'll paste the template of that page in your file, but you have to check the values (since i don't know what you may need):

```
version: '3.6'

services:
    traefik:
      image: traefik:1.7.12
      ports:
        - ${COMPOSE_PORT_HTTP}:80
        - ${COMPOSE_PORT_HTTPS}:443
      volumes:
        - "docker_mount:/var/run/docker.sock"
        - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
        - ./traefik/ssl/:/ssl/
        - ./logs:/logs
      container_name: traefik
      labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}"
          - "traefik.backend=traefik"
          - "traefik.port=8080"    

    nginx:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: nginx
      hostname: nginx
      volumes:
          - "nfsmount:../code_app/:/code_app/:rw"
          - "nfsmount:../code_email/:/code_email/:rw"
          - "nfsmount:../code_emailvalidation/:/code_emailvalidation/:rw"
          - "nfsmount:../code_msas/:/code_msas/:rw"
          - "nfsmount:../code_msms/:/code_msms/:rw"
          - "nfsmount:../code_mockserver/:/code_mockserver/:rw"
          - "nfsmount:./include/nginx_local/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro"
      depends_on:
          - php-fpm
      networks:
        default:
          aliases:
            - nginx-app-api
            - nginx-msms            
            - nginx-msas
            - nginx-mockserver
      labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=HostRegexp:{catchall:.*}"
          - "traefik.frontend.priority=1"
          - "traefik.backend=nginx"
          - "traefik.port=80"    

    app-redis:
      image: redis:alpine
      container_name: app-redis
      hostname: app-redis

    msms-redis:
      image: redis:alpine
      container_name: msms-redis
      hostname: msms-redis

    mockserver-redis:
      image: redis:alpine
      container_name: mockserver-redis
      hostname: mockserver-redis

    msas-redis:
      image: redis:alpine
      container_name: msas-redis
      hostname: msas-redis

    email-redis:
      image: redis:alpine
      container_name: email-redis
      hostname: email-redis

    phpredisadmin:
      container_name: phpredisadmin
      hostname: phpredisadmin
      image: erikdubbelboer/phpredisadmin
      environment:
          - REDIS_1_HOST=app-redis
          - REDIS_1_NAME=app-redis
          - REDIS_2_HOST=msms-redis
          - REDIS_2_NAME=msms-redis
          - REDIS_3_HOST=msas-redis
          - REDIS_3_NAME=msas-redis
          - REDIS_4_HOST=email-redis
          - REDIS_4_NAME=email-redis
          - REDIS_5_HOST=mockserver-redis
          - REDIS_5_NAME=mockserver-redis
      labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:redis-web.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}"
          - "traefik.backend=redis-web"
          - "traefik.port=80"

    mariadb:
      image: mariadb:10.2
      container_name: mariadb
      hostname: mariadb
      volumes:
        - "nfsmount:./backup:/backup"
      ports:
        - ${COMPOSE_PORT_MYSQL}:3306
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

    mongo:
      image: mongo:3.6
      command: --smallfiles
      container_name: mongo
      hostname: mongo
      ports:
        - ${COMPOSE_PORT_MONGO}:27017
      #environment:
      #  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      #  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

    mongo-express:
      image: mongo-express
      container_name: mongo-express
      hostname: mongo-express
      depends_on:
          - mongo
      labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mongo-express.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}"
          - "traefik.backend=mongo-express"
          - "traefik.port=8081"

    rabbitmq:
      image: rabbitmq:3-management
      hostname: rabbitmq
      container_name: rabbitmq
      #ports:
      #  # Management port
      #  - "15672:15672"
      #  # Service port
      #  - "5672:5672"
      labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:rabbitmq.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}"
          - "traefik.backend=rabbitmq"
          - "traefik.port=15672"
      #volumes:
      #  # Database mount
      #  - ./db_rabbitmq/:/var/lib/rabbitmq

    php-fpm:
      build:
        context: ./include/php-fpm
      container_name: php-fpm
      hostname: php-fpm
      # xdebug idekey "PHPSTORM"
      # xdebug port 9001
      volumes:
        # TimeFix
        #- /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        # GeoIP
        #- ./docker_files/db_geoip/:/application/storage/app/geoip2/
        # CRON
        #- ./docker_files/cron/php-fpm_laravel_schedule:/etc/cron.d/cron
        - "nfsmount:../code_app/:/code_app/:rw"
        - "nfsmount:../code_email/:/code_email/:rw"
        - "nfsmount:../code_emailvalidation/:/code_emailvalidation/:rw"
        - "nfsmount:../code_msas/:/code_msas/:rw"
        - "nfsmount:../code_msms/:/code_msms/:rw"
        - "nfsmount:../code_mockserver/:/code_mockserver/:rw"

    php-fpm-horizon:
      build:
        context: ./include/php-fpm-horizon
      container_name: php-fpm-horizon
      hostname: php-fpm-horizon
      depends_on:
          - rabbitmq
      volumes:
        - "nfsmount:../code_app/:/code_app/:rw"
        - "nfsmount:../code_msms/:/code_msms/:rw"        
        - "nfsmount:../code_email/:/code_email/:rw"
        - ../code_emailvalidation/:/code_emailvalidation/:rw
        - ../code_mockserver/:/code_mockserver/:rw
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:supervisor.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}"
        - "traefik.backend=horizon-supervisor"
        - "traefik.port=8001"

    phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      container_name: phpmyadmin
      hostname: phpmyadmin
      environment:
        #- PMA_ARBITRARY=1
        - PMA_USER=root
        - PMA_PASSWORD=root
        - PMA_HOST=mariadb
      depends_on:
        - mariadb
#      ports:
#        - 8080:80
      volumes:
        - /sessions
      labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:phpmyadmin.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}"
          - "traefik.backend=phpmyadmin"
          - "traefik.port=80"

    mailhog:
      image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
      container_name: mailhog
      labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mailhog.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}"
          - "traefik.backend=mailhog"
          - "traefik.port=8025"

    nodejs:
      image: node:9-alpine
      #build:
      #  context: ./include/vuejs-watch
      container_name: nodejs
      hostname: nodejs
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - "nfsmount:../code_app/:/code_app/:rw"
          - "nfsmount:../code_email/:/code_email/:rw"
          - "nfsmount:../code_msas/:/code_msas/:rw"
          - "nfsmount:../code_msms/:/code_msms/:rw"
      command: echo "Container ready."

    elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.8.2
        container_name: elasticsearch
        environment:
          - http.host=0.0.0.0
          - transport.host=localhost
          - network.host=0.0.0.0
          - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
        labels:
          - "traefik.enable=false"
        ulimits:
          memlock:
            soft: -1
            hard: -1
        networks:
          - default

    graylog:
        image: graylog/graylog:3.2
        container_name: graylog
        labels:
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.web.port=9000"
            - "traefik.web.frontend.rule=Host:graylog.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}"
            - "traefik.web.backend.healthcheck.path=/"
            - "traefik.web.backend.healthcheck.interval=10s"
        environment:
          # CHANGE ME (must be at least 16 characters)!
          - GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=somepasswordpepper
          # Password: admin
          - GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2=8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
          - GRAYLOG_HTTP_BIND_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9000
          # - GRAYLOG_HTTP_PUBLISH_URI=http://0.0.0.0:9000
          - GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI=https://graylog.${COMPOSE_BASE_DOMAIN}/
          - GRAYLOG_ROOT_TIMEZONE=Asia/Nicosia
        networks:
          - default
        depends_on:
          - mongo
          - elasticsearch
        ports:
          # Graylog web interface and REST API
          - 9000:9000
          # Syslog TCP
          - 1514:1514
          # Syslog UDP
          - 1514:1514/udp
          # GELF TCP
          - 12201:12201
          # GELF UDP
          - 12201:12201/udp

volumes:
    nfsmount:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
            type: nfs
            o: addr=host.docker.internal,rw,nolock,hard,nointr,nfsvers=3
            device: ":$PWD"

networks:
  default:
    name: intergo-local-net
    driver: bridge
```

Besides, I think is better if you rework any relative path in an absolute one when you need to use the NFS.

Adding some docs in case you want to check where thigs should be placed: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/